# How to tell Java Futures apart?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

It seems like I should be able to tell Futures apart from each other without having to maintain two HashMaps (or one bidirectional hash).

1. Future is known when job is submitted to ExecutorService. Add Future to map with key 'jobID'.
2. If job needs to be canceled, use 'jobID' in map to retrieve Future and cancel.
3. If job completes successfully, Future can be identified by the returned Object (containing job ID). Remove Future from map via 'jobID'.
4. If job is interrupted or throws an exception, no Object is returned, so the Future must be matched with the 'jobID' via calls to Future.hashCode or Future.equals (hence, two HashMaps or one bidirectional third-party hash).

Am I missing something here, or is that the expected approach? I'd like to override Future to include a 'getId' method or something, but that doesn't seem feasible based on how the executor creates them.

Edit: I'm also trying to use ExecutorCompletionService to wait for jobs to be completed.

Comment: why don't you just create a wrapper object and have a Future as a member field?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what do you want to achieve. You're looking for a way to cancel some `Future` objects, interrupt others and wait for completion of others?

Comment: Basically it's a job pipeline. An external source will be getting status and have the ability to cancel long-running jobs manually. The job might also throw an exception: that's the hard part that seems like it should be easier. How to link a Future back to the job it belongs to without using two HashMaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `java.util.concurrent.Future`. Use `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` or similar instead.
With `ListenableFuture`s you can register callbacks when a `ListenableFuture` completes:

```
ListenableFuture<Integer> future = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executor).submit(
  new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
      ...
    }
});

// Add jobId to the map. You should use a thread-safe Map!
map.put(jobId, future);

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Integer>(){
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(Integer result) {
    map.remove(jobId);
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    map.remove(jobId);
    ...
  }});
```

Comment: Broad stroke generalization statements such as 'never use this' are bad and often times (as in your cases) wrong. There are times to use futures and not listenable futures (and especially not 3rd party libraries). If you want to say he shouldn't use futures, say why

Comment: `Future` has a very poor set of methods, no ability to register a callback when a `Future` completes, no ability to register a fallback when a `Future` fails, no ability to set a timeout for a `Future`.

Comment: Thanks- I'm giving this a shot right now. The ability to define a subclass of FutureCallback with the jobId attached is already making me happier.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this (that I have previously used) is to create a `HashMap` which uses a `String` as the key, and a `Map.Entry` as the value. You can easily implement the `Map.Entry` interface yourself, but basically it provides a tuple structure which you can use to store the `Future` and its associated `hashCode`.

The benefit of this is that it allows greater control of the fate of your `Future` tasks once they have started (which I think is what you're getting at?). It is a little cumbersome, though. You can handle the cases of a successful task and a manually cancelled task by simply storing an ID for the `Future` objects in question.

This solution really only adds the ability to handle tasks that fail to execute correctly - in which case, assuming the number of potential tasks you wish to complete is reasonable, you may be better off simply handling the exceptions as they arise and maintaining a single `HashMap` of previous tasks (regardless of exit status).

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) for more on the `Map.Entry` interface.